# three.jsのモジュールであるFlyControlsの使い方がわかりません

Tags: javascript, three.js

プログラミング初心者で今勉強中です。某YouTuberの方の動画を見てthree.jsを勉強しているのですが、その勉強している内容の動画の中でthree.jsのFlyControlsを使うところで詰まっています。 FlyControlsをインポートする前までは正常に動くのですが、インポートのコードを打つと下記のようなエラーが出て困っています。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

その動画では正常に動いているのですが、約１、2年前の動画なので、やはり今とやり方が違うのでしょうか。解決方法を教えてください。

下記は今勉強中のコードです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>LensFlare Website</title>
<body>
 <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

そして、下記がjs(script.js)ファイルのコードです。

```
import * as THREE from "./build/three.module.js";
import {FlyControls} from "./jsm/controls/FlyControls.js";//このコードを打ったらエラーが吐かれました
```

```
let camera,scene,renderer;

init();

function init() {
    //カメラ
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15000);

    //シーン
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //geometry
    const size = 250;
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size);
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        specular: 0xffffff,
        shininess: 50
    });

    for(let i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        mesh.position.x = 8000 * (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0);
        mesh.position.y = 8000 * (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0);
        mesh.position.z = 8000 * (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0);

        //回転度合いをランダムに決める
        mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * Math.PI;
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * Math.PI;
        mesh.rotation.z = Math.random() * Math.PI;
        
        scene.add(mesh);
    }

    //平行光源
    const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.03);
    scene.add(dirLight);

    addLight(0.08, 0.3, 0.9, 0, 0, -1000);

    //ポイント光源を追加
    function addLight(h,s,l,x,y,z) {
        const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5, 2000);
        light.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
        light.position.set(x, y, z);
        scene.add(light);
    }

    //renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

VSCodeを使っています。htmlはVSCodeのOpen With Live Serverを使って開いています。three.jsの方はcdnではなくダウンロード版を使っています。

three.jsのバージョンはおそらくr153(0.153)だと思います。three.jsのサイトからダウンロードして展開してVSCodeに貼り付けています。ちなみにmacOSです。

**参考にした動画:**
[Three.jsでモダンな3Dウェブサイトの作り方 -Three.jsチュートリアル (YouTube)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=bdQf9vlfxdI&t=1133s)